# How to connect Visual SVN server on Windows from MAC?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am having a VisualSVN Server on Windows and I would like to connect the server from my MAC machine using a SVN client.

I can't find any suitable client UI.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find any suitable client UI.

What are the requirements for "suitable MAC SVN client"?

Have you tried these:

- svnX - https://code.google.com/p/svnx/
- Versions - http://versionsapp.com/
- XCode - https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: 1. my MAC is saying that "svnX can not be opened as it is belongs to unidentified developer" 2. Versions is not a free software & 3. Tried Xcode but not connecting to my existing VisualSVN server.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to fix that: http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/ 2. Ok 3. Do you see any error message?

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Let me try for no.1 and I'll keep you posted accordingly.